# SharePoint workflow sending email twice?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow on a list that sends an email if a column is set to a specific value. For some reason, the workflow sends two emails instead of one. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

I've checked the workflow to be manually started and automatically when an item is created.

Comment: Is this workflow running twice or just once? Can you it check in workflow settings for that particular item?

Comment: @GaneshSanap The workflow is running once, but it shows the log twice..

Answer (score 0):

You can check as follows:

1.Check if you have published two workflow for this list.

2.Go to the workflow history list and check if two items in it.

3.Create a new custom list, and create designer workflow to check if it still sending email twice.